# JavaScript flatten nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to flatten any length of a nested array into a single array. Why it's showing array rather than array value?

```js
function flatten(arr) {
  var res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (toString.call(arr[i]) === "[object Array]") {
      res.push(flatten(arr[i]));
    } else {
      res.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(flatten([1, 2, [3, [4, 5, [6]]], 7, 8]));
// [1, 2, Array(2), 7, 8]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing to `res` the result of `flatten`, which is an array. Instead [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the result of the inner `flatten` call to `res`, and assign the result to `res`.

Note: to identify an array, you can use [Array#isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

```js
function flatten(arr) {
  var res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      res = res.concat(flatten(arr[i]));
    } else {
      res.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(flatten([1, 2, [3, [4, 5, [6]]], 7, 8])); // [1, 2, Array(2), 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat` instead of `push` and `reduce` instead of `for` loop.

```js
const flatten = data => data.reduce((r, e) => {
  return r = r.concat(Array.isArray(e) ? flatten(e) : e), r
}, [])
 
console.log(flatten([1, 2, [3, [4, 5, [6]]], 7, 8]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method on the array as follows.

```js
function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.flat(10) //the number in brackets are the depth level 
}

console.log(flatten([1, 2, [3, [4, 5, [6]]], 7, 8]));
```